# unable to loop the object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a data like below

```
data = ["I253,J665,l2575"]
```

and I need the the results like

```
I253,
J665,
l2575
```

when i tried to use **for in**  i am getting like `I253,J665,l2575`  and I tried for loops also but not getting the result

```js
let data = ["I253,J665,l2575"]
for (let i = 0; i > this.data.length; i++) {
  console.log(i)
}

for (let x of this.data) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

tried converting the data in to string and then using split changed into array but then also i am getting typeof object only

below is my stack blitz url =: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-drf1dk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were having multiple mistakes. First one was with `for` condition it should be `i < this.data.length` not `i > this.data.length`. Then you need to split and loop over it with `for (let j = 0; j < data[i].split(',').length; j++)` so `data[i].split(',')[j]` will return expected value.

In case of `2nd` `for...of` loop you were simply logging whole value. Here also you need to split inside `for...of` and use one more loop to log.

Alternatively you can also use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and loop over it like `for (let m of data.flatMap(x => x.split(',')))`.

Try it below. You can use `this.data`, but it won't work in below example so it is used as simply `data`.

```js
let data = ["I253,J665,l2575"];

console.log("Using for loop");
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < data[i].split(',').length; j++) {
    console.log(data[i].split(',')[j]);
  }
}

console.log("Using for...of loop");
for (let x of data) {
  for (let y of x.split(',')) {
    console.log(y);
  }
}

console.log("Using flatMap");
for (let m of data.flatMap(x => x.split(','))) {
  console.log(m);
}
```

Comment: Ok but this split method will break if i have one value right say like ["I253"] is the only value i have

Comment: No, it won't break. Give it a try. `"I253".split(',')` will return `["I253"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `data` variable like below:

```
data = ["I253", "J665", "l2575"];

for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){
  console.log(this.data[i]);
}
```

If you have `data` variable as `data = ["I253,J665,l2575"];`

Then split it first and then loop through the generated array:

```
const arr = data[0].split(',');
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr[i] + ',');
}
```

Comment: i tried to modify it to string and from there to array using .split('',')  that is also not working

Comment: tried converting the data in to string and then using split changed into array but then also i am getting typeof object only

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to solve this.
Also note that your loop is wrong **SHOULD NOT BE** **'>'** and **Should Be '<'**

**1. Your data is at array index zero so if you are to keep the data as is**

```
let data = ["I253,J665,l2575"]
let splits = data[0].split(',')
for (let i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
  console.log(splits[i])
}
```

or

```
let data = ["I253,J665,l2575"]
let splits = data[0].split(',')
for (let element of splits) {
  console.log(element )
}
```

**2. Fix the data string**

```
let dataString = "I253,J665,l2575"
let splits = dataString.split(',')
for (let i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
  console.log(splits[i])
}
```

or

```
let dataString = "I253,J665,l2575"
let splits = dataString.split(',')
for (let element of splits) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

**Clone of the example provided in question**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-izj7up

Comment: Ok but this split method will break if i have one value right say like ["I253"] is the only value i have

Comment: Well it does not https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4xf1qh